# How to validate the combination of .p8 file, KeyId, TeamId and BundleId in APNs token-based authentication

Tags: php, ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've a .p8 file, KeyId, TeamId and BundleId of the app, now I want to do check whether is that validate stuff or not?

If that stuff are not valid then it will not delivered iOS push notification to the devices. is that possible before send the notification to the device?